# Catching MDX queries without profiler

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx, business-intelligence

How I can catch MDX running queries without profiler? I looks for something like DMV sys.dm_exec_requests, but for SSAS.

Comment: you can't without profiler (AFAIK). Also, why can't you use profiler?

Comment: I cannot use profiler on production database.

Comment: Can you use Flight Recorder?  https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&aq=&oq=ssas+flight+recorder&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4GGNI_enUS551US551&q=ssas+flight+recorder&gs_l=hp...0l2j0i22i30l3.0.0.1.2546692...........0.JZC176LunLQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running SQLServer 2012+ maybe you can use [Extended Events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492139.aspx).

There are indeed some [DMV's](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/johndesch/2013/05/13/using-dmvs-to-monitor-and-terminate-long-running-mdx-queries/) for running sessions, connections and commands.